# How to split a paragraph into small sub-strings?

Tags: java, string, nlp

I am trying to remove English words from a string or (Paragraph). But the problem is all the words are not being removed. But when i try the same with a smaller string say of 25 words, it works perfectly.
I am trying to filter this in 3 steps:

1. Remove Links from a String
2. Remove XML Tags.
3. Remove English words.

Below is the code:

```
String SWList[];
public ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
String sentenceSoFar="";
String nextToken;
String withoutLink=null;
ArrayList<String>    wordscount = new ArrayList<String>();
boolean flag=false;
String str;
int counter;
String finalStr="";
ArrayList<String> spaceCheck = new ArrayList<String>();

public void removeLinks(String str) {
    sentenceSoFar=null;
    String delims = " ";
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, delims);
    sentenceSoFar=null;
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String str1 = "http";
        String nextToken = st.nextToken();
        //System.out.println("LINK CHECK : " + nextToken);

        if (!(nextToken.contains(str1))) {
            flag = false;
            if (counter == 0) {
                tokens.add(nextToken);
                sentenceSoFar += " " + nextToken;
                withoutLink+= " " + nextToken;
            } else {
                if (nextToken.contains(str1)) {
                    withoutLink = nextToken;
                    counter=1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //System.out.println("sentence wala :  " + sentenceSoFar);
    removeXmlTags(sentenceSoFar);
    sentenceSoFar=null;

}

public void removeXmlTags(String strTags) {
    //strTags=null;

    String[] stopWords = new String[] {
        "&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;",
        " &amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt; ",
        ".&lt;/p&gt;"," .&lt;/p&gt; ",
        "1??&quot;&gt;&lt;span&gt;&amp;nbsp;",
        " 1??&quot;&gt;&lt;span&gt;&amp;nbsp; ",
        "&lt;p"," &lt;p ",
        "  align=&quot;center&quot;&gt; ",
        " align=&quot;center&quot;&gt;",
        ";",
        "&",
        "/&",
        "&lt",
        " &lt ",
        "_rdEdi",
        " _rdEdi ",
        "br",
        " br ",
        "gt",
        " gt ",
        "exLink",
        " exLink ",
        "link",
        " link ",
        "&gt",
        " &gt ",
        "style",
        " style ",
        ";/div& ",
        "class",
        " cestry ",
        "-",
        " - ",
        "nb",
        " nb ",
        " a ",
        "&lt;p&gt;",
        "&#160;",
        ";/b&",
        ",",
        "/",
        " It ",
        " strong ",
        " span ",
        " Responsibilities ",
        " bull ",
        " amp ",
        " b ",
        " d ",
        " e ",
        " f ",
        " g ",
        " h ",
        " i ",
        " j ",
        " k ",
        " l ",
        " m ",
        " n ",
        " o ",
        " p ",
        " q ",
        " r ",
        " s ",
        " t ",
        " u ",
        " v ",
        " w ",
        " x ",
    };

    {
        for (String stopword : stopWords) {
            strTags = strTags.replaceAll("(?i)"+stopword, " ");
        }
    }

    //System.out.println("OUTPUT STRING WITHOUT TAGS : " + strTags);
    englishWords(strTags);
    strTags=null;
}

public void englishWords(String strWords) {

    finalStr=null;
    String[] stopWords = new String[]{
        " i " , " a " , " natural " , " and " , " if " ," your" ," about " , " an " , " are " , " as " , " at " , " be " , "  by " ," was " ," leadership " ,
        " com " , " for " , " from " , " how " , " in " , " is " , " it " , " not " , " of " , " on " , " or " , " that " , " the " , " this " , " to " , "lt","quot",
        " what " , " when " , " where " , " who " , " will " , " with " , " the " , " www " ," role " ," provides" ," you " ,"&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt; " ,"align","temp","tor",
        " Inc." ,"  Inc." ," is " ," an " ," equal" ," equal " ," Opportunity" ," Opportunity " ," Employer" ,"  Employer " ,"  The " ," company" ," candidates" ,"center",
        " company " ," its" ," affiliates" ,"  affiliates " ,"  recruit " ,"  hire " ,"  qualified " ," candidates" ,"  candidates " ,"  today " ," Facebook " ,
        " without " ,"  without " ," regard" ,"  regard " ," to " ," race" ," race " ," religion" ," religion " ," color " ," color " , " sex " ," sexual " ,
        " sexual " ,"  orientation " ,"  orientation " ," gender " ," gender " , " identity " ," identity " ," age " ," national " ," national " ," origin" ,
        " origin " ," ancestry" ," ancestry " ," citizenship" ," citizenship " , " veteran" ," veteran" , "  or " ," disability" ,"  disability " ," status" ,
        " status " ,"  medical" ,"  medical " ," condition" ," condition " ," marital" ," marital " , " any" ,"  any " , " other" ,"  other " ," factor" ,"  factor " ,
        " prohibited" ,"  prohibited " ," state " ,"  state " ," provincial" ,"  provincial " ," and " ," federal" ,"  federal " ," municipal" ,"  municipal " ,
        " it " ," ul " ," LI " ," HR " ," div " ," it " ," ul " ," lt " , " sp " , " Nurse " ," join " ," our " ,"  Overview " ,"  specializes " ,"  highly " ," sampling " ,
        " Description " ," Requirements " ," Intensive " ," Care " ," StartDate " ," ASAP " ," Available " ," Shifts " ," Exclusive " ," order " ," Serving " ,
        " throughout " ,"  county " ," members " ," range " ," more " ,"  provide " ," Emergency " ," currently " ," customer " ,"  unparalleled " ,"  Spending" , 
        " looking " ," Critical " ," Facility " ,"  boggling " ," entertainment " ," service " ," benefits " ," commitment " ," outdoor " ," comprehensive " ,
        " settings " ," patient " ,"  exhilarating " ,"  interventions " ,"  environments " ," nurses " ," needs " ," travel " ,"  primary " ," see " ,"  experience" ,
        " gas " ,"  transportation " ,"  machine " ,"  construction " ," mining " ," industries " ," detailed " ," corrective " ,"  action " ,"  both " ," management " ,
        " management " ,"  Receiving " ,"  Inspection " ," verification " ," established " ," which " ," material " ," acceptance " ," measurement " ,
        ," training " ," Familiar " ,"  shipment " ,
        " levels " ,"  drawings " ," knowledge " ," Recruiter " ," Recruiter: " ,"  long " ," short " ," years " ," opportunities " ," competition " ,"  until " ," Email " ," here " ," quot " ," replace " ," schedule " ," Flexible " ,
        " these"  ," can " ,"  manage " ,"  multiple " ," tasks " ," simultaneously " ," adapt " ," market " ," changes? " ," basic " ," qualifications " ," only " ,
        " half " ," story " ,"  considering " ," 7 " ," eleven " ," right " ," choice " ," should " ," consider " ," they " ," possess " ,"  traits " ," most " ," common " ,
        " successful " ," 7 " ,"  eleven " ,"  franchisees " ," can "  ,"  train " ,"  supervise " ," employees? " ," willing " ," empower " ,"  them " ," delegate " ," them? " ,
        " dedicated " ," operations "  ," excellence? " ," do " ,"  focus " ," details? " ," committed " ," creating " ," managing " ," organization " ,"  effectively " ,
        " recruits " ,"  trains " ,"  retains " ,"  motivates " ," people " ," do " ,"  have " ,"  desire " ,"  build " ," emental " ," me " ,"  through " ," execution " ," ability " ,
        " programs " ,"  strategies? " ,"  do" ,"  have " ,"  food" ," can " , " aur " , " join "
    };

    for (String stopword : stopWords)
    {
        strWords = strWords.replaceAll("(?i)"+stopword, " ");
    }

    String delims = " , = ; : ' * % $ @ 0 - _ + ( ) .";
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(strWords, delims);

    finalStr =null;
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {

        String ntoken = st.nextToken();
        //    System.out.println("LINK CHECK : " + ntoken);

        tokens.add(ntoken);
        finalStr += " "+ ntoken;
        //withoutLink+= " " + nextToken;

    }

    //    System.out.println("Different  STRING : " + finalStr);
    //    new indexing.IndexAlgo().algoOne(finalStr);
    finalStr=null;
}
```

I would really appreciate if anyone can help me with some better logic or code.

Comment: Thats one of a hell spaghetti code ... =o

Comment: @Maciej Cygan:  Me thinks that OP might not have coded this stuff himself and thus is why he doesn't understand the code.

Much of it is nonsense.

Comment: I don't understand what your point of the else statement in the while loop of the `removeLinks` method. `counter` stays 0, so what's the point? And, why do you set flag to false? It's not being used anywhere. Did you intend for counter to be incremented with every iteration of the while loop? 

 
FYI, your first method will definitely work, with the exception that you'll have a `null` value at the start of your resulting string. But, there's quite a bit of code which you can do without.

Answer (score 0):

First and third methods look like they should work in spite of their strange lines of code which make no sense.  But, I haven't really looked at the second one in depth, I guess because I'm not that strong with Regular Experssions.  I thought that you're supposed to use `/p` along with a unicode property.  I don't know what the expression `\p` is supposed to mean here.

I'm not sure what kind of input you're using and what your results are.  Why do you think that your code isn't working?

Comment: Input string is in XML format which i have already parsed and i have passed it to removeLink method. Now i want to remove link first followed by XML tags and then all English words...

Comment: The first two methods works properly but i have issue with the third method. Suppose the length of a paragraph is small say 25 words then all the words which are in stopWords Array gets filtered but when the length of a string 1000 or 1500 words its doesn't get filtered. So i want to remove all the English words or all the words which are in stopWords Array when englishWord method is being executed